# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg'

Tags: matplotlib, kivy, pyinstaller, kivymd, modulenotfounderror

I've had a problem for a few days now when I try to convert my kivy python application that uses matplotlib into an executable (.exe). Each time I get this error `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg'"`. Yet in the dist folder `( "C:\Users\Patrick-Lévy N'da\oneDrive\Bureau\dev\dist\main\kivy\garden\matplotlib" )` I have the `backend_kivyagg.pyc` file. And when I run my program it works perfectly without error. Once I remove the part that uses matplotlib, the conversion works perfectly.

Here is my main.spec file:

```
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=['kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg'],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=True,
)

a.datas += [("assets/trajets_type/trajets1.csv", "C:\\Users\\Patrick-Lévy N'da\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\dev\\assets\\trajets_type\\trajets1.csv", "DATA")]
a.datas += [("assets/trajets_type/trajets2.csv", "C:\\Users\\Patrick-Lévy N'da\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\dev\\assets\\trajets_type\\trajets2.csv", "DATA")]
a.datas += [("assets/img/icon.png", "C:\\Users\\Patrick-Lévy N'da\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\dev\\assets\\img\\icon.png", "DATA")]
a.datas += [("assets/img/logo.png", "C:\\Users\\Patrick-Lévy N'da\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\dev\\assets\\img\\logo.png", "DATA")]
a.datas += [("assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf", "C:\\Users\\Patrick-Lévy N'da\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\dev\\assets\\fonts\\Poppins-Regular.ttf", "DATA")]
a.datas += [("assets/guide.txt", "C:\\Users\\Patrick-Lévy N'da\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\dev\\assets\\guide.txt", "DATA")]

a.datas += [("assets/screens_designs/matty.kv", "C:\\Users\\Patrick-Lévy N'da\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\dev\\assets\\screens_designs\\matty.kv", "DATA")]
a.datas += [("assets/screens_designs/home_page.kv", "C:\\Users\\Patrick-Lévy N'da\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\dev\\assets\\screens_designs\\home_page.kv", "DATA")]

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [('v', None, 'OPTION')],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='main',
    debug=True,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
    icon=['assets\\img\\icon.ico'],
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe, Tree('C:\\Users\\Patrick-Lévy N\'da\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\dev\\assets\\'),
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='main',
)
```

And I use

```
Kivy==2.2.1
Kivy-Garden==0.1.5
kivy-garden.graph==0.4.0
kivy-garden.matplotlib==0.1.1.dev0
kivy-matplotlib-widget==0.6.1
matplotlib==3.7.2
pyinstaller==5.6.2
```

I've done a lot of research and watched videos on youtube but I still haven't found the solution. Whether I try my pyinstaller command line with or without the --hidden-import I get the same results. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From which directory do you run the installer, or rather how are the paths of the `main.spec` and your application files related?

My guess would be, that the import does not look at the appropriate directories and thus does not find the `matplotlib` files. Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096377/trying-to-import-a-pyc-as-a-module) regarding the import of *.pyc files includes some hints?

Comment: I have a dev folder containing all the code for my virtual environment, the main.spec file and all the other program files. And in main.spec I put the path from the root to the files I want to add. So when I launch without the part that's not found, the .exe file works correctly. From my dev folder, when I look in the build folder created by pyinstaller, the file kivy/garden/matplotlib/backend_kivyagg.pyc exists.

Comment: The same goes for my .\env\Lib\site-packages\kivy\garden\matplotlib\backend_kivyagg.py . Or do I have to add it as data in my main.spec file or do I have to indicate the path from the root in the hidden-import for it to work?